# How can I get the likes source metrics?

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm trying to get info for these metrics https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights/#like_sources.

But it seems none of these metrics works. I've tried this:

```
graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT metric, value FROM insights WHERE object_id = 256781961002361 AND metric = 'timeline'
```

And also:

```
graph.facebook.com/256781961002361/insights/timeline
```

But I keep getting this:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#604) Invalid metric name: timeline",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 604
  }
}
```

Any ideas?